# MiKTeX package management

Tags: packages, miktex, directory

When I first installed MiKTeX and started using it, I had to install a bunch of extra package that had been included in my `.tex`. I did this by using the MPM, etc.

Now I'm about to uninstall MiKTeX but I want to keep those installed packages for future usage. So next time I can just make local repository and install them. **Where are the user-installed packages saved?**

And if the setups are not preserved after installation. How can I keep them in the future? Of course I could just download them from the packages website of MiKTeX. But just asking. I run on a very limited bandwidth.

Comment: I'm a bit confused here: you don't say why your are uninstalling MiKTeX. Packages themselves are installed either in the MiKTeX install tree ('Admin' mode use of MPM) or inside `%appdata%` (per-user install). However, that's just the files TeX needs, and won't allow you to add them back in to the MPM list. Could you perhaps expand a bit on what the overall aim is here?

Comment: @JosephWright Basically. To save bandwidth. Before I uninstall MikTex. I wish to make a backup of all the packages I installed post-installation of Miktex. So once I re-install Windows (which the bigger plan) and then re-install Miktex. I can just put them back in without using Internet. Is there a way one could do that?

Comment: By default, under MikTeX, downloaded packages are installed at `C:\Users\[your user name]\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex`

Answer (score 2):

Well, it depends how you have installed your MiKTeX and how you do your updates.

If you use the basic MiKTeX installer or the net installer you had to answer the question where the dowloaded file should be saved.  So MiKTeX first downloads the files to this directory and then starts installing with the files from this directory.

If you do not want to download these files again, copy this directory to the new computer, call your installer and choose once again this directory.